# What methods can I use to quantify the impact of multiple variables on a response variable?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, regression-coefficients, structural-equation-modeling

Suppose I have observations for both the predictors ${x_1,x_2,...,x_p}$ and the response $y$, what I am interested in is the controls of these predictors on the response $y$. There are several cases we couldn't know for sure: (1) whether there are interactions among these predictors and even high-order interactions, (2) whether there are other predictors that was not considered yet in the model. I want to know what kind of methods can I use to quantify the controls of the considered predictors on the response $y$?

Maybe someone will say "regression", but as far as I know, it is sensitive to multicollinearity (although there are ways like 'lasso' that can address it, but the coefficients will be biased if lasso was used). In addition, regression is used most often for prediction, which in my case is not required.

Here is an example using MATLAB showing why lasso gives biased coefficient:

```
clear;
clc;
nbsample = 1000; % sample size
nbtrial = 5000; % number of experiments

% Simulation parameters
a = 2.5;
b = 0.3;
c = -1.4;
d = -0.8;

% Covariance matrix
sigma_eps = 0.8;
rho = 0.85; % correlation between x1 and x2
mu = [0, 0, 0];
Sigma = [1, rho, 0; rho, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1];

excep1 = zeros(nbtrial, 1); 
excep2 = zeros(nbtrial, 1); 
lasso_b1 = zeros(nbtrial, 1);
lasso_b2 = zeros(nbtrial, 1);
lasso_b3 = zeros(nbtrial, 1);

for iexp = 1:nbtrial
   D = mvnrnd(mu, Sigma, nbsample);
   x1 = D(:, 1);
   x2 = D(:, 2);
   x3 = D(:, 3);    
   noise = randn(nbsample, 1)*sigma_eps;
   y = a + b*x1 + c*x2 + d*x3 + noise;

   x4 = rand(nbsample, 1)*1.5;

   R2X = [ones(nbsample, 1), x1, x2, x3, x4];
   [R2bs, ~, ~, ~, ~] = regress(y, R2X);
   excep1(iexp, 1) = R2bs(5);

   B = lasso([x1, x2, x3, x4], y, 'Lambda', 0.0475);
   excep2(iexp, 1) = B(4, 1);
   lasso_b1(iexp, 1) = B(1, 1);
   lasso_b2(iexp, 1) = B(2, 1);
   lasso_b3(iexp, 1) = B(3, 1);
end

figure("Position", [50, 50, 800, 120]);
subplot(1, 5, 1);
histogram(excep1, 50);
title(['x4:', 'classical']);
subplot(1, 5, 2);
histogram(excep2, 50); 
title(['x4:', 'lasso']);
subplot(1, 5, 3);
histogram(lasso_b1, 50); 
title(['x1:', 'lasso']);
subplot(1, 5, 4);
histogram(lasso_b2, 50); hold on;
plot([b+c, b+c], [0, 100], 'r-', 'LineWidth', 1.5); hold off;
title(['x2:', 'lasso']);
subplot(1, 5, 5);
histogram(lasso_b3, 50); hold on;
plot([d, d], [0, 100], 'r-', 'LineWidth', 1.5); hold off;
title(['x3:', 'lasso']);
```

This is the result:
[image: Figure 1: The regression coefficients distribution using LASSO]

You can see that LASSO could help select significant features (keep $x_2$ and $x_3$, while remove correlated $x_1$ and insignificant variable $x_4$), and the coefficient for $x_2$ is meaningful (approximately equal to $b+c$), but the coefficient for $x_3$ is biased.

Comment: Multicollinearity, unless it is so extreme that it causes floating point math issues, is just an issue for doing inference on the parameters. Regression away! // So what of the LASSO parameters are biased? If you get that your model has ability to explain the response variable $y$ with enough accuracy, you have a strong argument that your predictor variables influence $y$.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: What is your update supposed to show?

Comment: Could you explain to us what you mean by a "control of a predictor"?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you care about the bias in your coefficients but not about the MSE?

Comment: @whuber Here "control of a predictor" means "effect" of predictor variable on the response variable. In one word, I want to figure out which predictor is the most important one affecting the response (also the second, third, ...). The only way I can think of is to use the regression coefficients to represent their effects. But it is well known that regression coefficients are not necessarily reliable due to the presence of multicollinearity. Then I have the question above. Thank you.

Comment: @Kuku The reason is that I want to use the regression coefficients to interpret the effect of predictor variables on the response variable. If it is biased, interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: Your coefficient estimate could be unbiased but highly variable, in which case for a specific study or realization of its estimation, you could also be wrong in your interpretation. Hence why I ask if there is a specific reason you care specifically about the bias source in your error, echoing the sentiment in @Dave 's first comment.